# Unable to locate package ros-melodic-ros-base on Ubuntu Mate 18.04

Tags: ros-melodic, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Ubuntu Mate 18.04 on a old machine and I get this "unable to locate package ros-melodic-ros-base" error. I tried using the desktop and desktop-full version too, and they all have the same error. I don't if it has anything to do with it, but I'm using the 32-bit version of the OS. Other then that I don't what could be causing this error, do you guys have any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327792/unable-to-locate-package-ros-melodic-ros-base-on-ubuntu-mate-18.04/) by [pretel](https://answers.ros.org/users/44005/pretel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I'm using the 32-bit version of the OS

That would explain it: as you can see in [REP-3: Target Platforms - Platforms by Distribution - Melodic Morenia (May 2018 - May 2023)](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#melodic-morenia-may-2018-may-2023), only `amd64` (for x86 architectures) of Melodic is supported with packages on the ROS buildfarm.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pretel](https://answers.ros.org/users/44005/pretel/) on 2019-07-07**:
I see that. I choose the 32-bit OS because its running on a very old machine, with only 2Gb of RAM. But I thing I don't have a choice and must install a 64-bit OS. Thanks for the help!!